# How to batch insert into two tables with one's id is another's foreign key?

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables. Table User has columns as below

```
ID,NAME,AGE
```

And Table Asset has columns as below

```
ID,ID_USER,PRICE
```

Asset's ID_USER is the ID of User.

Table User's id uses sequece seq_t_user.
Table Asset's id uses sequece seq_t_asset.

Now There are 1000000 users waiting to be inserted. We can use for loop to process every record seperately.

`v_id_user = seq_t_user.nextval();
insert into User values(v_id_user, 'Lilie', 20);
insert into Asset values(seq_t_asset.nextval(), v_id_user, 1000);`

But this is very time consuming. Is there any way to batch insert into two tables at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "unconditional multitable insert" is what you need.

I assumed you get all the values from my_table but you can modify as you need;

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ ALL
INTO USER (ID,NAME,AGE) 
    values (seq_t_user.nextval(), name, age)
INTO ASSET (ID,ID_USER,PRICE) 
    values (seq_t_asset.nextval(), seq_t_user.nextval(), price)
with MY_VALUES as
    (select /*+ parallel */ 
         name,
         age,
         price
     from my_table)
select /*+ parallel */ * from MY_VALUES
```

edit: We learned that we can't use sequence in multitable insert in the select statement. So we moved the sequence to the insert part.

Comment: This hurls *ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here*

Comment: I think it's because I use it in a subquery, if we remove the subquery it can work, I will try and edit this.

Comment: Hi @deniz, the ID_USER of ASSET should be a foreign key referring USER . We should guarantee for each record, thery are exactly the same. Here I see that you used seq_t_user.nextval(), so I wonder they may be two values.

Comment: Hi Robin, when i run the script, I realized that it calculates nextval() only once for each iteration. So, it has the same value for two inserts.

Comment: @deniz, yes. You are right. Multiple calls of nextval in a statement will return the same value.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use INSERT ALL. This allows us to populate several tables from one SELECT source. My example uses `dual` so you will need to change that to suit your purposes:

```
insert all
into t_user (id, name, age) 
    values (seq_t_user.nextval, name, age)
into t_asset (id, id_user, price) 
    values (seq_t_asset.nextval, seq_t_user.nextval, price)
select 'ROBIN' as name
        , 23 as age
        , 1200 as price
from dual
union all
select  'APC' as name
         , 42 as age
         , 1100 as price
from dual
;
```

Here is [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3b4fef/1).

Comment: I also thought about seq_t_user.nextval and seq_t_user.currval. Is there any way to ensure that they are exactly the same?

Comment: actually we can use `values (seq_t_asset.nextval, seq_t_user.nextval, price)`. multiple calls of `nextval` in a statement will return the same value.